# Apache Ignite Stripped ThreadPool allocated bytes keep increasing and GC is not able to reclaim those bytes

Tags: memory-leaks, threadpool, ignite

We are stuck in a memory issues with our ignite cluster

I am running locally 3 nodes on a Windows 10 machine

We do a lot of cache putAll and read operations and I have explicitly set the stripped pool size to 24

The behavior that we are seeing is that the sys-strip threads keep allocationg memory and is not being freed up by GC, even when threads are idle

Has anyone seen or resolved this issue?

Comment: Avnish, could you please share the configuration and code blocks with cache putAll and read operations

Comment: Did you run into out-of-memory? JVM can delay the moment, when it frees up memory, until the heap usage is higher than some threshold.